# Error 403 after deploying Asp Net Core 2.2 website on Godaddy

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, c#-4.0, .net-core

I have deployed my website developed in Asp net core 2.2 on Godaddy server.
After deploying I received error 500. As discussed with the Godaddy support I removed Web.config file.

Then it started throwing error 403. There is full permission to all folders and subfolders. I have searched a lot but unable to find any solution also Godaddy support is also not satisfactory.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried running your website locally to see whether it works fine? Also, check with GoDaddy support whether they have the .net core 2.2 sdk installed on the server.

Comment: @AzharKhorasany its running perfectly in local. Yes Godaddy has 2.2 installed as per the support team.

Comment: This could be lot of things, starting from DNS not configured correctly to some error somewhere in the code. Have you checked the Event Viewer logs on the server? Also, can you install fiddler on the server and check?

Comment: @AzharKhorasany  I have checked the logs on the server its only showing error 403. no more relative information. Its not possible to install fidler on the server as its third party server.

Comment: @MayankBhuvnesh Make sure you have setup your default page and change your application pool to no managed code. You can refer to this post https://windowswebhostingreview.com/troubleshoot-403-error-when-publishing-asp-net-core/

Comment: @MarkSpencer Wat should I set in default documnet since it is MVC based structure?

Comment: @MayankBhuvnesh Please check with your provider, please ask them to install MVC on their server. That's why you received above error message.

Comment: @MarkSpencer I am using Godaddy Server which has all the required services and softwares installed.

Comment: @MayankBhuvnesh If MVC has been installed properly, your site will work without any issue. I also use .net here. If they can't make it work, change your hosting, you can try Asphostportal. I also host my site with them.

Comment: I found a non-official solution. You can refer to my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59788549

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment yet, otherwise I would. However:

Removing the web.config may not have been the correct move. My guess is now IIS has no idea that it should be running a .Net Core app, and instead tries to directory browse, which is disallowed so you receive a 403.

I'd also be wary now if you went and added full permissions on everything.

I would suggest re-deploying it from scratch and turning on the 'stdoutLogEnabled' in the web.config temporarily. Then the site should at least attempt to run again, and record an error log in the folder specified by the 'stdoutLogFile' path in the web.config.

More about stdoutLog here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/aspnet-core-module?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Comment: When I add Web.config file I get 500 error. So as suggested by the support team I removed Web.config.