# .NET Core 3.1 cannot host on Plesk self-contained, getting errors: 500 - Internal server error & HTTP Error 502.5 - Process Failure

Tags: plesk, .net-core-3.1

I have used two different host services with *Plesk Onyx 17.8.11*, but still I am not able to run my application on the hosts.

So here are the things I have done so far:

- I published using self-contained winx64 mode and updated web.config to `hostingModel="InProcess"`.. still, I was getting 500 - Internal error.
- I tried to turn on logging through web.config `stdoutLogEnabled="true"` and no files were created in that directory and I couldn't figure out why!
- I changed modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" to modules="AspNetCoreModule" based on some recommendations (as a dirty trick) and then I got HTTP Error 502.5 - Process Failure.
- I tried both methods of web deploy and folder deploy and then transferring to the server through [FileZilla](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FileZilla).

As far as I understood there isn't any need to install the Microsoft .NET bundle as I'm using the self-contained method.

Comment: This post can help you, please check https://windowswebhostingreview.com/asp-net-core-hosting-3-simple-steps-to-fix-502-5-error-in-asp-net-core/. One thing again, make sure that your provider has support/installed .net core on their server.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately, the link you have sent is not related to Plesk hosts. Many hosts such as shared Godaddy host are using Plesk which supports up to .net core 2.2 (and not 2.2 itself), and it doesn't allow you to install dot net core runtime on the server. The article regarding best ASP.NET Core hosts on the website talks about the older version of dot net core... I ended up changing my host to Azure.

Comment: I also use Plesk here, Plesk doesn't officially support .net core, so your hosting provider must install .net core on their server and set your application pool to no managed code. Good choice to choose Azure. I personally use Asphostportal to host .net core.

Comment: Make sure you have created necessary folder to let app just place the log files into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I want to give an update. I went through multiple websites, including [GoDaddy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GoDaddy). Their shared hosting Plesk Onyx 17.8.11 supports up to ASP.NET 2.0 version and if you want to get a higher version you need to use their [VPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_private_server) or dedicated server's plans which costs a fortune...

*[Does GoDaddy's shared Windows hosting plan support ASP.NET Core?](https://au.godaddy.com/community/Plesk-Hosting/Does-GoDaddy-s-shared-Windows-hosting-plan-support-ASP-NET-Core/td-p/90819)*

Answer (score 1):

This help document explains Plesk's ASP.NET Core support. *[ASP.NET Core support in Plesk](https://support.plesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/115000442805-ASP-NET-Core-versions-in-Plesk)*. If you expect to host anything in 3.1, you need an alternative solution.

There are other places to host ASP.NET Core 3.1 applications for a decent price, however. For example, AspHostPortal seems to have a lot of good deals and is recommended by Microsoft.
*[Comparison of All Windows Shared Hosting Plans](https://asphostportal.com/Windows-Shared-Hosting-Plans.aspx)*

You can also use [Azure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Azure), although that can get expensive if you want SSL.

If you are still looking for alternative solutions, here are some resources that might be helpful.

A similar Reddit question: *[Hosting ASP.NET 3.1 on GoDaddy](https://www.reddit.com/r/dotnet/comments/hbspf7/hosting_aspnet_31_on_godaddy/)*

A tutorial with several options:
*[Best fast & cheap Windows shared hosting For ASP.NET Core](https://dottutorials.net/best-fast-cheap-windows-hosting-asp-net-core/)*

Answer (score 1):

I found a non-official solution to this question and running ASP.NET Core 3.1 on the [GoDaddy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GoDaddy) Windows web hosting.

The solution as follow:

1. Use self-contained to build your project.
2. Edit web.config and you just need to change WebApplication1.dll to your DLL file name on this example.

   ```xml
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <configuration>
     <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
       <system.webServer>
         <handlers>
           <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />
         </handlers>
         <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\WebApplication1.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="true" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="inprocess" />
       </system.webServer>
     </location>
   </configuration>
   ```
3. Upload your project files to GoDaddy.
4. Access your URL and you can see it's successfully running ASP.NET Core 3.1.

Reference: *[[ASP.NET Core] Godaddy .NET Core 3.1?](https://exfast.me/2020/09/how-to-running-asp-net-core-3-on-godaddy/)*